# Django show all objects and foreach object all compatible objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I am new to Django and I want to create a compatibility model for mobile phone. I create a model with all phone details like name, screen size etc. and I thought of creating a new model for compatibility.

The first model in Django

```
class MobilePhone(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(MobileManufacturer, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    dimensions = models.TextField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    display_type = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    display_size = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
```

and another model for compatibility

```
class Compatibility(models.Model):
    comp_id = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    comp_type = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    mobile_id = models.ForeignKey('MobilePhone', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I fill the MobilePhone table with values

| id | name | manufacturer | dimensions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Phone 1 | Samsung | 8x15 |
| 2 | Phone 2 | Samsung | 8x15 |
| 3 | Phone 3 | Samsung | 8x15 |
| 4 | Phone 4 | Samsung | 8x15 |

and the Compatibility table with

| id | comp_id | comp_type | mobile_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | screen | 1 |
| 2 | 100 | screen | 2 |
| 3 | 101 | screen | 3 |
| 4 | 100 | screen | 4 |

**the comp_id is the unique number I use to group the phones**

now with

```
all_entries = MobilePhone.objects.all()
```

get all mobile phones like

```
- Phone 1
- Phone 2
- Phone 3
- Phone 4
```

what I want is

```
- Phone 1
-- (same with Phone 2, Phone 4)

- Phone 2
-- (same with Phone 1, Phone 4)

- Phone 3
-- (no compatibility)

- Phone 4
-- (same with Phone 1, Phone 2)
```

I do not know if my thinking is correct. I may be wrong in the way I design the model or if there is a simpler way. I would appreciate any help or advice

Comment: Can you describe you question and required output more clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should not be a problem to make a nested for loop. I would use print() for simplicity, but the same can be applied to the Django templating system.

```
for mobile in MobilePhone.objects.all():
    print('-', mobile.name)
    compatibles = list(mobile.compatibility_set.all())
    if not compatibles:
        print('(no compatibility)')
    else:
        comp_list = ', '.join((c.name for c in compatibles))
        print(f'-- (same with {comp_list})')
```

Okay, I've cheated a bit, since you cannot use list comprehensions in the template. However, you could extract the `comp_list` to the method in the Mobile model and use that in the template. Or create a template tag ([there is already one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#join)), or make the computations in the view and provide a list of tuples to the template, you choose.

Comment: I think that the easiest way is to extract the `comp_list` from model but I dont know the way

Comment: what makes it complicated for you? it's just a simple code construct, a function of a class

Comment: Yes, you are right. As I say... new to programming. Some things are not clear in the mind. Thank you @Alexandr for helping